# HerokuでDockerを導入していたらError: Exec format errorでアプリが表示できなくなりました

Tags: docker, heroku

#### 環境

ruby 2.6.5
rails 6
MySQL
M1チップ搭載macOS

#### 解決したいこと

HerokuでDockerを導入していたらError: Exec format errorでアプリが表示できなくなりました
表示させるにはどうした良いでしょうか？

#### 発生までの流れ

heroku container:push web -a <アプリ名>
heroku container:release web <アプリ名>

heroku run rails db:migrate

ここで下記エラーが起こりました。

#### 発生している問題・エラー

**ターミナル**

```
Error: Exec format error
```

#### その他のエラー

その後、heroku run rails c
でも上記エラー
git push heroku masterを実行したらerror: failed to push some refs toのエラーが発生しております

#### heroku logs

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 該当するソースコード

**Dockerfile**

```docker
FROM ruby:2.6.5

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl apt-transport-https wget && \
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
apt-get update && apt-get install -y yarn

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs yarn
RUN mkdir /fridge_app
WORKDIR /fridge_app
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock /fridge_app/
ENV BUNDLER_VERSION 2.1.4
RUN gem update --system \
    && gem install bundler -v $BUNDLER_VERSION \
    && bundle install -j 4
COPY . /fridge_app

RUN yarn install --check-files
RUN bundle exec rails webpacker:install

ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/local/src/bin

COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    platform: linux/amd64
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: root
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/mysql

  web:
    build: .
    environment:
      region: ap-northeast-1
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/fridge_app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Comment: おそらく Heroku 側のサーバは x86_64 アーキテクチャ なので M1 フォーマットな docker image を実行できないのだと思います。[Build multi-platform images](https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx/#build-multi-platform-images) を参照すると、x86_64 対応の docker image を作成する必要がありそうです(ここで `--platform` オプションを設定する)。

Comment: 解決しました！コメントありがとうございました！